# Is there a search space algorithim I could use for this function?

Tags: r, search

Is there a way to find the values that are sufficient to pass this function? What's the best algorithm that will find the search space of this algorithm?

```r
pnor <- function(p1, p2, p3){
  
  if(isTRUE(p1*p1 != p1)){
    return(FALSE);
  } 
  else{
    return(isTRUE(p2*p3 == p2 || p2*p3 == p3));
  }
}
```

I know (1,1,1). I know its random.

Side note: what's the flowchart of this going to look like?

Comment: Your conditions are equivalent to the one-liner `isTRUE(p1 == 1 && (p2 == 1 || p3 == 1))`.

Comment: There are some things here that are unclear to me. What does "I know it's random" mean?  Can you give us a little context for the problem?

Comment: @RuiBarradas:  You missed $(1, 0, x)$ and $(1, y, 0)$ which are solutions for any $x$ and $y$ values.

Comment: @user2554330 Damn! "Divide by" doesn't include zeros...

Comment: Your conditions are equivalent to the one-liner `isTRUE(p1 == 1 && (p2 %in% 0:1 || p3 %in% 0:1))`.

Comment: Initially I wanted to make truth tables that extend to operations but that made no sense so initially I wanted to use a nor function and this popped out. That's why its called pnor.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your logic can be simplified as

```
pnor <- function(p1,p2,p3) {
    p1%in% c(0,1) & any(c(p2,p3)%in%c(0,1))
}
```